# Как все элементы одного списка перенести в конец другого?

Tags: python, list

Люди у меня появился вопрос, как все элементы одного списка перенести в конец другого без повторений.

```
mass_3 = [[2,3,4],[5,3,3],[8,9,3]]
mass_4 = []
truelen = "3"

for i4 in mass_3:
    mass_4.append("_")
    for i5 in i4:
        if str(i5) == str(truelen):
            f3 = [i6 for i6, ltr in enumerate(i4) if ltr == i5] 
            print(f3)

#f3 = [1]
#f3 = [1,2]
#f3 = [1,2]
```

данных повторений быть не должно, но они почему то есть, а это для меня очень критично.

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста, что вы пробовали делать.

Comment: Вообще у меня в проекте проблема несколько в другом, у меня есть отрезок кода, я прикреплю его к посту и прикреплю то что он выдаёт, он повторяет значения, хотя по сути такого быть не должно, поэтому я хочу попробовать через копирование одного списка в другой.

Comment: Если сможете, то ответьте мне как можно более разумно и без повторений узнать индексы повторяющихся символов в тексте

Comment: На выходе что должно получится?

Comment: На выходе должно получиться следующее:

Comment: [1]; [1,2];[2];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mass_3 = [[2,3,4],[5,3,3],[8,9,3]]
mass_4 = []
truelen = 3

for arr in mass_3:
    mass_4.append([i for i, el in enumerate(arr) if el == truelen])

print(mass_4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если решать основную задачу *"все элементы одного списка перенести в конец другого без повторений"*, то это вроде работает:

```
mass_3 = [[2,3,4],[5,3,3],[8,9,3]]
mass_5 = []
for arr in mass_3:
    mass_5.extend(arr)

mass_x = list(set(mass_5))
print(mass_x)
```

даст

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```